# Is there a term for a married couple who have the same christian and surname?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, terminology, vocabulary

My wife and I share the abbreviated form of our name - Alex derived from Alexandra and Alexander respectively. As we are married, we have the same christian and surname when used in the short form.

I was wondering if anyone is aware of a term for this? I would assume one exists because I know of several examples i.e. Sam(antha) and Sam(uel) Clark the chefs who are known as Sam and Sam Clark.

Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I’d say the term for that situation is *confusing*. :)

Comment: Why bring religion into it?

Comment: @Robusto He didn’t.

Comment: @tchrist But 'Alexander' isn't a Christian name, it's Greek, right?

Comment: @robusto - Replace 'christian' for 'first name' if you prefer.

Comment: @tchrist - yep, very surprised by the number of people who don't understand the distinction between Alexandra and Alexander.

Comment: I do not at all understand the use of the term "christian" as used in either sentence here.  It's quite confusing.

Comment: @SouthpawHare: almost worth an ELU question...I looked it up...it's an older ([currently not common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=christian+name%2C+Christian+name%2C+first+name%2C+First+name&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) )way of referring to given name ('first name' in English culture)  as opposed to family name ('last name').

Comment: @SouthpawHare As Mitch said, it's a term referring to the given names of a person, as opposed to their surname. Etymologically, it comes from the religious practice of 'christening,' a kind of naming ceremony practiced by many Christian faiths. The term has largely fallen out of use in America, but is still widely recognized in Australia, the UK, and some other English-speaking countries.

Answer (score 2):

We just say we're in a *same-name* relationship.

> Chris and Chris

Answer (score 1):

How about *homonymic*, the adjective form of *homonym*, meaning "same name."